# Bootstrap 3 multilevel menu with angular-strap (without jquery)

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am working on an angular js 1.3.x project using bootstrap 3. I combine both by using angular-strap library 2.3.12 and I have to add submenus on my menu. I 've seen that bootstrap 3 removed submenus and i have seen a few solutions on the web but all of them use jquery. I don't want to use jquery as I have faced many compatibility issues when using with angularjs.

Can you suggest how to add multilevel support (up tp 3 levels) with angular-strap?

Sample code (not working so far)

```
$scope.nav = [{
          label: 'Pages',
          value: 'pages',
          children: [{
              label: 'Home',
              value: 'home'
          }, {
              label: 'Left Nav',
              value: 'left-nav'
          }]
      }, {
          label: 'Components',
          value: 'components'
      }];

<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <li ng-class="{'dropdown':(n.children.length)}" ng-repeat="n in nav">
        <a data-target="#" data-toggle="{{n.toggle}}">{{n.label}}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="p in n.children"><a href="#/">{{p.label}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The "*Without jQuery*" demand is a little bit odd since twitter bootstrap 3 requires jQuery. Perhaps you mean "without javascript"...?

Comment: Angular uses a jquery lite version and the original jquery has many incompatibilities - with angular.